# simple_form not saving content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to create a simple blog app using simple_form

In my new.html.erb for Post, I have the following code

```
<h3>Write your blog post here</h3>
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :content %><br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In index.html.erb, I got

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
  <p>Post: <%= post.content %></p>
<% end %>
```

However, I am getting the following on my index page for Post

```
[#<Post id: 1, created_at: "2015-09-07 23:07:54", updated_at: "2015-09-07 23:07:54", content: nil>, #<Post id: 2, created_at: "2015-09-07 23:07:54", updated_at: "2015-09-07 23:07:54", content: nil>, #<Post id: 3, created_at: "2015-09-07 23:08:11", updated_at: "2015-09-07 23:08:11", content: nil>,
```

Here is my Post Controller

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[post_params])
      if @post.save
        success = true
        message = "Nice!"
      else
        success = false
        message = "Sucks!"
      end
      redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

Here is my model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And finally, the migration to add content column to Post

```
class AddContentToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :content, :string
  end
end
```

After typing the text in my Post, I am able to create it. But I am not sure if it's being saved as the content says "nil". This is very frustrating as it seems like a very simple problem. After hours of trying to figure out what's going on, asking for help here...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

First, this line:

```
<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
```

Needs a `<%`, not a `<%=`.

`<%=` outputs the result of the expression. The result of `array.each` is an array, and that's what you're seeing the browser.

Second, your accessing of `params` is wrong. You're using

```
@post = Post.new(params[post_params])
```

You use `params[:post]`, or you use `post_params`, but you don't do both. You're trying to use the return value of `post_params`, which is an Hash of keys and values, *as a key* to access `params` again. You need either of these:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
# or
@post = Post.new(post_params)
```

Comment: When I remove the "=" sign, there is no data being displayed. Now it just shows up as blank..